# SimpleUrlHandlerMapping NoSuchFieldError: null

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the following error on initialization of my webapp. Has anyone seen this one before?

This occurs where spring is attempting to load SimpleUrlHandlerMapping

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

here's the contents of my lib directory:

```
thom@motion:~/workspace/gxt-ui/war/WEB-INF/lib$ ls -l
total 8228
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom 5434137 2012-01-11 21:59 gwt-servlet.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom  589253 2012-02-17 13:48 org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom  829601 2012-02-17 13:46 org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom  442400 2012-02-17 13:50 org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom  540819 2012-02-17 14:01 org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thom thom  572266 2012-02-13 10:49 org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: What does your Spring configuration for the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was missing one of the Spring libraries being used by the application and it was throwing a bad exception. In my case, the missing library was: org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The artifact is:
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by having both Spring 3.0.X and 3.1 on your build path.  Check the output of mvn dependency:tree, or the WEB-INF/lib directory of your finally packaged artefact?

I encountered this as Spring Security 3.1 pulls in Spring core libraries at 3.0.X, not 3.1.

For Maven, you can (and should) fix this by using the  tag to ensure all the relevant dependencies are at the same Spring version:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- spring-security-taglibs:3.1.0.RELEASE pulls in 3.0.6 of this -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- spring-security-web:3.1.0.RELEASE pulls in 3.0.6 of this -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I don't think that's it. I'm pretty sure everything is 3.1. I've added the contents of my lib directory to the question.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not using Maven, so I control all of my dependencies with ant.